# Is this method of creating objects only applicable for singleton objects?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I was going through some code written by Douglas Crockford. He uses the below structure to create objects.

```
var obj = (function(){
    var x, y, z;   // These are private fields

    // This is private method
    function func1() {
    }

    return {
        // This is public method
        init : function() {
        }
    };
}());
```

I like this way as opposed to the constructor functions like below.

```
function Obj() {
    // Uses __ to denote private
    this.__x = 0;
    this.__y = 0;
    this.__z = 0;

    // Private method
    this.__func1 = function() {
    };

    // Public method
    this.init = function() {
    }
}
var obj = new Obj();
```

I don't like the constructor function method as you need to use __ for denoting private fields or methods (and this does not really make the field private) and you need to use this keyword for accessing any field or method. I like the first method but I don't know how to define multiple objects using it.

Can we define multiple objects in the first method or it can only be used for creating singleton objects?

Comment: Do you mean multiple objects as in many instances of obj?

Comment: @adriaanp Yes I mean multiple instances

Answer (score 0):

To instantiate new objects you need to use the new keyword that needs to use a function as a constructor. I see 2 options:

Return a function instead of object literal in your function:

```
var obj = (function(){
    var x, y, z;   // These are private fields

    // This is private method
    function func1() {
        console.log("func1");
    }

    return function() {
        // This is public method
        this.init = function() {
            func1();
        }
    };
})();
```

Or don't use a self executing function:

```
var obj = function(){
    var x, y, z;   // These are private fields

    // This is private method
    function func1() {
        console.log("func1");
    }

    return {
        // This is public method
        this.init = function() {
            func1();
        }
    };
};
```

Both let's you do var newObj = new obj(). Not sure what are the implications between the two but I normally just use a function.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that:

```
this.__x
```

does not make x private (except possible by convention, i.e people learn not to use that)

rather:

```
function Obj() {
    //  private
    var x = 0;
    var __y = 0;

    // public
    this.z = 0;

    // Private method
    function func1() {
    };

    // Public method
    this.init = function() {
    }
}
```

I found this link helpful: http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/